# Ошибка в вычислениях с большими числами - pow(10,54)

Tags: c++, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Почему при выполнении этого кода получается 0, а должно быть 123?

```
int b = pow(10,54)+123-pow(10,54);
qDebug() << b;
```

Comment: потому что 123 это практически ничего по сравнению с десятью в пятьдесят четвертой степени, и места в мантиссе 10^54 для 123-х нет - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @Igor но ведь ТС работает с интом, наверно вот этот момент и неясен - когда что во что преобразуется и где теряется.

Comment: @Kromster возможно, Вы правы в смысле неясности - целым все это становится только в момент присвоения `b`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Точность представления числа с плавающей точкой имеет свои границы, увы, не доходящие до 54 знаков. Поэтому прибавление 123 к 10<sup>54</sup> нисколько не меняет *представление* 10<sup>54</sup> в переменной типа `double`.

Кстати, вы здесь проводите вычисления с типом `double`, который затем приводите к `int` - но, думаю, вы и сами это понимаете...